# Не корректно показываются иконка font-awesome

Tags: css

Почему не показывается иконка лишь квадратик маленький, который нельзя сдвинуть или увеличить.

Не понимаю уже, может какая-та проблема с порядком стилей?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/style.css">
<link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="assets/img/favicon.png">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Work+Sans:300,400,500,600,700,800" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display:400,400i,700,700i,900" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/lightslider.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/css/font-awesome.css">
```

Сам код

```
 <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-down" aria-hidden="false"></i></a>

   .fa-chevron-circle-down {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5em;
    background-color: black;
    }
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А зачем подключать font-awesome.css и font-awesome.min.css вместе? А если подключить отсюда http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.0.3/css/font-awesome.css ?

Comment: @РашенБеар Вроде бы заработало, но почему оно работает именно так? как можно исправить?

Comment: в файле font-awesome.css прописано правило font-face со ссылками на файлы шрифтов(.eot, .woff, .ttf и пр.). Скорее всего адреса в url() не совпадают с реальным расположением файлов шрифтов.